# How to get instance objects to change position horizontally

Tags: python, instance, maya

I'm creating an instance python command where the primary purpose is to generate objects in neat horizontal rows. Even though I can randomize rotation and set the range, I still can't figure out how to get the objects to appear in horizontal rows.

I already tried to use the xform command to get the objects to move along the x coordinates.

```
import maya.cmds as MC
import random as RN

def ChainmailGenerator():
    thing = MC.ls(sl=True)
    print thing

    if not thing:
        MC.error (" ***Error - you need to select an object *** ")

    # create a group node
    grp = MC.group(empty=True, name=thing[0] + '_grp#')

    #Loop though the items below with the range of a
    for i in range (0,25):

        instanceObj = MC.instance(thing, name=thing[0]+'instance#', smartTransform=True)

        rx = RN.uniform(-1,1)*5
        ry = RN.uniform(-1,1)*5
        rz = RN.uniform(-1,1)*5

        MC.rotate (rx,ry,rz, instanceObj)
        MC.xform (r=True, ro=(90, 0, 0) )

        tx = 5

        MC.xform ( instanceObj, t=(0,15+1,0))

        MC.parent (instanceObj,grp)      

    print "*** chainmail ***"

ChainmailGenerator()
```

The expectations are for the objects to generate in horizontal increments as if they're forming neat rows.

Answer (score 0):

here is an example to create 10 spheres along x, moving them with xform :

```
step = 1
tx = 0
for x in range(10):
    sphere = cmds.polySphere()[0]
    cmds.xform(sphere, t=[tx,0,0])
    tx+= step
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason yours is placing everything in the same place now is because you aren't multiplying it against a value that keeps increasing. Normally you could hard-code some random value to space each one out, but this would yield inconsistent results.

Here's a generic way to go about it that seems to work with any object.
The idea is to use the mesh's bounding box to determine what the spacing should be by looking at the size of its x axis. You can also move it in place with `xform`, but you do need to include its `worldspace` parameter so that it doesn't move it relative to its current position.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds


def cloneInRow(count):
    # Get selection.
    thing = cmds.ls(sl=True)
    if not thing:
        cmds.error("You need to select an object")

    # Get selection's mesh shape.
    mesh = cmds.listRelatives(thing[0], shapes=True, f=True, ni=True, type="mesh")
    if not mesh:
        cmds.error("Unable to find a mesh on the selected object")

    # Determine spacing by looking at object's bounding box. Use its `x` axis size.
    bb_min = cmds.getAttr(mesh[0] + ".boundingBoxMin")[0]
    bb_max = cmds.getAttr(mesh[0] + ".boundingBoxMax")[0]
    spacing = bb_max[0] - bb_min[0]

    # Create a root transform to parent to.
    grp = cmds.group(empty=True, name=thing[0] + '_grp#')

    # Create instance, and move it in place.
    for i in range (0, count):
        instanceObj = cmds.instance(thing[0], name=thing[0] + 'instance' + str(i), smartTransform=True)
        cmds.xform(instanceObj, ws=True, t=(i * spacing, 0, 0))
        cmds.parent(instanceObj, grp)

    cmds.select(grp)


cloneInRow(10)
```

With this I can take this crossbow:

[image: clone]

And clone any of its objects and get nice spacing:

[image: clone]
[image: clone]
[image: clone]

The only catch is rotation. If your pivot isn't centered to the mesh, then randomizing its rotation will lose its place in space (since rotating would also effects its position!) So if you got weird pivots then it won't look nice when you add back on rotations.